# searching for sublime_text 4 text short key (: (that maybe not exist)

Tags: c, sublimetext3, sublimetext4

I just want to find some short key for sublime text 4 that maybe not even exist (I tried to find it on google so if he exist sry my bad X:)...

**question:** sometimes I write program that will be easier to test (if it working correctly) using comments, I mean by that comment everything else what inside the same function without that piece of code that I wanna test.

**for ex:** (I just wanna run, print hello 3 and hello 4)

*#librarys ...*

*int main(){*

//printf("hello 1");

//printf("hello 2");

**printf("hello 3");**

**printf("hello 4");**

//printf("hello 5");

*return 0;*
}

(im using c if its relevant)
someone knowing some info that could be helpful?

Comment: You could select the whole function, comment that, and then select what you want to uncomment and uncomment that.

Comment: You can use the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) for conditional compilation.

Comment: @PiRocks yea I probably do something similar to that every time but its not so officiant and sometimes when you uncomment these lines some lines still will be comment

Comment: @Sercan ty I will undarstand what u mean by that in next year.

Comment: ty guys and happy new year!

Comment: Why not just highlight the sections you want to comment and hit `Ctrl-/`? You can have multiple regions selected at the same time...

Comment: hey @MattDMo I personally using : 'Ctrl - shift - /', I think its little bit better for me... sometimes when u want to run specific code u probably dont want to waste your time to find every piece of code that u dont rly need and because of this reason I think its will be very helpful sometimes just to mark and press on specific short key to comment others lines of code in the function.